# What is $\;\mathbb{E}[p(X,Y)/p(X)p(Y)]\;$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables. Let $p(x,y)$ be the joint p.d.f. and $p(x),p(y)$ be the marginal p.d.fs. My question is: What is
$$\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}\!\left[\frac{p(X,Y)}{p(X)p(Y)}\right] = \iint \frac{p(x,y)^2}{p(x)p(y)} dx dy$$

What is the meaning of this quantity? And is there any work that studies this?

Background: I am working on a course project about estimating a certain quantity, and after some computation that quantity is equivalent to this quantity, so I am wondering what this quantity means.

Update: This is an information theory course, so probably this has something to do with information theory. If I am not mistaken, $\mathbb{E}_{X,Y}\!\left[\text{ln} \frac{p(X,Y)}{p(X)p(Y)}\right]$ is the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Why does $E[F(X,Y)]=1$ hold? If I am interpreting your notation correctly, $E[F(X,Y)] = \sum_x \sum_y \frac{P(X=x, Y=y)}{P(X=x) P(Y=y)} P(X=x, Y=y)$.

Comment: What is $P(X)$?

Comment: @angryavian I made a mistake. Should not be an expectation. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: That is the expected value of the random variable $Z,$ where $Z$ is defined as $Z = p(X,Y) / p(X) p(Y).$

Comment: @WilliamM. Oh right. I just found out that I made a mistake previously. Thanks!

Comment: If you want an intuitive meaning, the best I can think of is that if $X$ and $Y$ were independent, then $Z$ would be equal to 1, and therefore its expected value too. However, in average, $Z$ can be a little less than $1$ and a little more than $1$ so that the expected value is still $1$ but $X$ and $Y$ are not mutually independent. So, I would not think this is used for that.

Comment: If we will change this quantity a bit, we will get $\mathbb{E} ln \left[\frac{p(X,Y)}{p(X)p(Y)}\right] = H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y)$, where $H(Z)$ is entropy of $Z$.

Comment: @sergeinikolaev You are right. The expectation of the log of this is the mutual information between X and Y. I will put this in the post.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "meaning" in your question? Are you looking for properties of the functional, what it characterises, something else? In any case, this is equal to $\exp(I_2(X;Y)),$ where $I_2$ is the Renyi mutual information of order $2$, and also equal to $1 + \chi^2(P_{XY} \| P_X \otimes P_Y)$ (called the chi-squared divergence). Both $I_2$ and $\chi^2$ are pretty well studied, and you might find useful intuition on looking them up.

Answer (score 1):

The quantity $r(x,y)=\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}$ is the (Radon-Nikodym) derivative of $(X,Y)$ with respect to $X\otimes Y$, same as in the general definition of the mutual information.
The quantity $\mathbb E[r(X,Y)]$ you're looking at is the expected derivative under $(X,Y)$.

Recall the $\chi^2$-divergence $\chi^2(U\|V)$ with $U=(X,Y)$ and $V=X\otimes Y$, and notice that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[r(X,Y)]&=\mathbb E[r(U)]=\mathbb E[r(U)+r(U)^{-1}-2]+1=\mathbb E[r(U)^{-1}(r(U)-1)^2]\\
&=\mathbb E[(r(V)-1)^2]+1
=\chi^2(U\|V)+1,
\end{align*}
using that $u\mapsto r(u)^{-1}$ is the derivative of $V$ with respect to $U$. Notice that $\chi^2(U\|V)=\chi^2((X,Y)\|X\otimes Y)$ is the mutual information induced by the $\chi^2$-divergence, analogously to the mutual information $I(X,Y)=D((X,Y)\|X\otimes Y)$ induced by the relative entropy.

Thank you, stochasticboy321, for pointing out the $\chi^2$-divergence!

Comment: The functional is equal to $1 + \chi^2(P_{XY} \|P_X \otimes P_Y),$ where  the $\chi^2$ divergence is generated by $u \mapsto (u-1)^2.$ Another way to write it using standard functionals is $\exp(I_2(X;Y)),$ where $I_2$ is the 2-Renyi mutual information.

Comment: Thank you Matija and @stochasticboy321 for the answers! My goal is to estimate this quantity with data sampled from $p(x,y)$. Your answers are very useful.